# when i cancel the dio the file deleted from storage

Tags: flutter, dart, download, dio, cancellation-token

I want to cancel the download opration in dio flutter
I use the TokenCancel to stop downloading but when I use like

```
     Tokencanel.cancel();
```

the whole file deleted from my Storage
and I just want to stop downloading and file still exist

I tried to use other thing to stop that but thats the only way